# WooCommerce logout endpoint not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to sort this out for around 3 hours now and I'm at a total loss.

I can't logout of my WordPress site. I created a new test customer, disabled all plugins accept WooCommerce, activated the basic Twenty-Fifteen theme, have the default "customer-logout" endpoint set in WooCommerce but clicking the logout button in the My Account page just returns me in a loop back to the My Account page with the user still logged in.

Manually adding wp_logout(); to a page will log a user out so there seems to be issue with the endpoint not triggering wp_logout();.

Anyone have a similar issue or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: What does the logout URL link look like?

Comment: Hi Andrew,
I have redesigned the my-account page and tried various URLs such as:
http://www.example.com/my-account/customer-logout/ 
As well as:
http://www.example.com/?customer-logout=true

However even when I disable my custom my-account page and the URL reverts back to the default URL that includes the _wpnonce like this:
http://www.example.com/my-account/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=2765879b79

...it still won’t work. I click logout, get a message to confirm if I want to log out, I click yes then end up back at the my-account page with the users details still shown.

Comment: With the default WordPress theme 2017 and WooCommerce there is no confirmation message for me when you click logout.

Comment: I just don’t understand what’s wrong. Latest test: Reinstalled Wordpress, reinstalled WooCommerce, disabled all plugins, updated and activated Twenty Thirteen theme. The logout link is: http://example.com/my-account/customer-logout/?_wpnonce=134c3a6e83. I click the link, end up on a new screen with “You are attempting to log out of Example. Do you really want to log out?" I click yes, I end up back at my-account page with user still logged in and all details still shown. Pulling my hair out…and there’s not much of it left already!

Comment: Try 2017 theme.

Comment: just to confirm... this is a woocommerce related problem... as can be seen in `~/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-my-account.php`

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in wordpress functions.php, to auto logout customer/user after payment in woocommerce or close the browser

```
function logged_in( $expirein ) {
   return 6; // 6 in seconds
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'logged_in' );

function wp_logout2() {
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();

    /**
     * Fires after a user is logged-out.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_logout2' );
}

function wpse108399_change_cookie_logout( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ){
    if( $remember && user_can( $user_id, 'administrator' ) ){
        $expiration = 604800;// yes, I know this is 1 minute
    }
    if( $remember && user_can( $user_id, 'editor' ) ){
        $expiration = 604800;// yes, I know this is 1 minute
    }
    }
    return $expiration;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration','wpse108399_change_cookie_logout', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Bypass logout confirmation.
 */
function iconic_bypass_logout_confirmation() {
    global $wp;

    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['customer-logout'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( str_replace( '&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'iconic_bypass_logout_confirmation' );
```

A part of this code it's for increase expiration time to administrators of wordpress or other kinds of user

```
function wpse108399_change_cookie_logout( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ){
    if( $remember && user_can( $user_id, 'administrator' ) ){
        $expiration = 604800;// yes, I know this is 1 minute
    }
    if( $remember && user_can( $user_id, 'editor' ) ){
        $expiration = 604800;// yes, I know this is 1 minute
    }
    }
    return $expiration;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration','wpse108399_change_cookie_logout', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can not able to logout
then try this link
http://yousite.com/?customer-logout=true

Comment: Not sure if this link ever worked, but in 2021 it definitely doesn't. It will just redirect the user to a non-existing page, resulting in a 404 page experience, furthermore the user remains logged in.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that clicking the logout link would take the client to the front-end client dashboard where a confirmation message in the notifications area would wait for the client to click it.

I ended up bypassing this confirmation using the code from [here](https://mylisting.club/bypass-woocommerce-logout-confirmation/):

```
    add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'log_out_customer' );
    function log_out_customer() {
      global $wp;

      if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['customer-logout'] ) ) {
         wp_redirect( str_replace( '&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) );
         exit;
      }
   }
```